# MySQL: can't recreate table (errno: 150), after dropping index in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can see many posts about this but apparently none similar to my specific issue.

I created my table:

```
CREATE TABLE ANOTHER_TABLE (ID_ANOTHER_TABLE BIGINT PRIMARY KEY);
create table EXAMPLE (TYPE varchar(10) not null, EXAMPLE_NUMBER integer default '0', ID_ANOTHER_TABLE bigint not null, primary key (TYPE, ID_ANOTHER_TABLE)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table EXAMPLE add index FK_h9owxl7oyju8ue8b97u7ldei (ID_ANOTHER_TABLE), add constraint FK_h9owxl7oyju8ue8b97u7ldei foreign key (ID_ANOTHER_TABLE) references ANOTHER_TABLE (ID_ANOTHER_TABLE) on delete cascade;
```

Then I wanted to drop it to create it again with lots of changes. Instead of simply dropping it, in PHPMyAdmin I went to the table structure page and I firstly clicked to drop the index from the foreign key (**I mistakenly thought I was dropping the foreign key**):

```
ALTER TABLE `EXAMPLE` DROP INDEX `FK_h9owxl7oyju8ue8b97u7ldei`;
```

**It dropped ok, although it shouldn't**. In command line I would receive the error  `Cannot drop index 'FK_h9owxl7oyju8ue8b97u7ldei6': needed in a foreign key constraint.`

But it showed no error, apparently executing it successfully, and then I clicked to drop the primary key next:

```
ALTER TABLE `EXAMPLE` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

But this time I got the error:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of './mydb/#sql-b6bd_2a9e7' to './mydb/EXAMPLE' (errno: 150)
```

**And then the table vanished**. If I try to drop it, I get `#1051 - Unknown table 'EXAMPLE'`.

And if I try to create the table again, this is what I get:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'mydb.EXAMPLE' (errno: 150) (Details…)
230228 14:43:40 Error in foreign key constraint of table mydb/EXAMPLE:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_h9owxl7oyju8ue8b97u7ldei" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_ANOTHER_TABLE") REFERENCES "ANOTHER_TABLE" ("ID_ANOTHER_TABLE") ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So apparently the constraint got stuck, and I can't drop it since the table doesn't exist anymore. **Is there any way I could clean this, without dropping the schema**?

MySQL 5.5.62
PHPMyAdmin 5.0.1

Thanks

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` report?

Comment: @BillKarwin 5.5.62-log

Comment: That's a very old version, it has been out of support since 2018.

Comment: I don't have a version to try to test, but I note that dropping an index is not the same as dropping a foreign key constraint. I would guess that's what messed up the metadata and led to the problems. I would recommend dropping the schema and starting over. Refrain from dropping indexes that are needed to support the foreign key. Drop the FK constraint instead if you need to.

Comment: *PHPMyAdmin I firstly dropped the foreign key ... It dropped ok* I don't believe you. You must receive an error with the error message *Cannot drop index 'FK_h9owxl7oyju8ue8b97u7ldei': needed in a foreign key constraint*. https://dbfiddle.uk/kWS2btgC

Comment: @Akina that is true, I just tried it in command line and received this error. But as I said, I used PHPMyAdmin (5.0.1) and there it was possible. Anyway, any ideas how to clean this bad data? I edited my post to include all this information discussed in the comments.

Comment: *But as I said, I used PHPMyAdmin (5.0.1) and there it was possible.* Enable General Log temporarily and look the queries which are received by your server **really**.